# Unknown prop warning react js `iconClassNameRight`

Tags: html, css, reactjs, meteor

Hi there I want to know why it is throwing a warning on the console

```
Warning: Unknown prop `iconCLassNameRight` on <div> tag. Remove this prop from the element. For details, see link fb me
    in div (created by Paper)
    in Paper (created by AppBar)
    in AppBar (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in MuiThemeProvider (created by App)
    in App
```

The is the code I am working on it is on meteorjs and material ui

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';

import Player from './Player.jsx';
import TeamList from './Team-list.jsx';
import TeamStats from './Team-stats.jsx';

export default class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div className="container">
          <AppBar
            title="Soccer Application" iconCLassNameRight="muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more" showMenuIconButton={false} />
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col s12 m7"> <Player /> </div>
              <div className="col s12 m5"> <TeamStats /> </div>
              <div className="col s12 m5"> <TeamList /> </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </MuiThemeProvider>
      )
    }
  }
```

I want to know why this is throwing an error. The line of interest is in the appbar component iconClassNameRight property. Any help would be greatly appreaciated. Thank you.

Comment: The error is in the Paper component but your're showing App. Paste Paper as well so we can see the props flow from one to another (and the propTypes will be helpful as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Props in React are case-sensitive.

Try replacing `iconCLassNameRight` (uppercase L) to `iconClassNameRight` (lowercase L)